# Javascript - modify a specific part of an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, var, console.log

I am a real beginner and I started to learn java script,
I am following a course and I am trying to reproduce a step in Visual Studio but when I run the code I get no result.

```js
var myArray = [10, 20, 30];
myArray[1] = 25; // myArray now equals to 10, 25, 30
console.log(myArray)
```

when running this myArray should go from 10,20,30 to 10,25,30
but instead nothing happens, not even an error.
Other parts of the code I write do give me an answer, so is not an issue with Visual Studio.

Can you see what I do wrong?
Thanks a lot
Nic

Comment: Where and how do you see that nothing happens? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Your snippet works just fine.